# Regular expression to extract whole sentences with matching word

Tags: regex

I would like to extract sentences with the word "flung" in the whole text.

For example, in the following text, I'd like to extract the sentence "It was exactly as if a hand had clutched them in the centre and flung them aside." using regular expression.

I tried to use this `.*? flung (?<sub>.*?)\.`, but it starts searching from the beginning of the line.

How could I solve the problem?

> As she did so, a most extraordinary thing happened. The bed-clothes gathered themselves together, leapt up suddenly into a sort of peak, and then jumped headlong over the bottom rail. It was exactly as if a hand had clutched them in the centre and flung them aside. Immediately after, .........

Comment: What's the expected output for the above input?

Comment: The expected output is "It was exactly as if a hand had clutched them in the centre and flung them aside.". And your code works perfectly. Thank you Avinash!

Comment: If you preprocess your text through a sentence analyzer which breaks out each sentence to a separate line, this part becomes easy, and your sentence-determining logic no longer has to fit in a single regular expression.

Comment: What is your regex engine / language / implementation?

Comment: @Unihedron I use Emeditor. Different Regex engines use different regular expression by which I'm always confused.

Answer (score 31):

Here you go,

```
[^.]* flung [^.]*\.
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/7)

OR

```
[^.?!]*(?<=[.?\s!])flung(?=[\s.?!])[^.?!]*[.?!]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/10)

Comment: Thanks Avinash you saved the day. Technically the OP asked for the word "flung" (no spaces) which should be: [^.]*flung[^.]*\.

Comment: If there are two of the same word in a sentence is there anyway to get two copies of the sentence around the word?

Comment: Could you suggest a regex to properly extract sentences containing decimals? ('.' shouldn't be treated as fullstop in '5.25ml')

Comment: `\b\d+\.\d+\b` try this

Answer (score 4):

Simply anything between dots:

without a dote

```
[A-Za-z," ]+word[A-Za-z," ]+
```

with a dote

```
[A-Za-z," ]+word[A-Za-z," ]+\.
```

Comment: ... except when your text contains punctuated abbreviations, viz. this far-flung example.

Comment: @tripleee You're right. How to tackle this problem with "-" connected with the match word? Thank you!

Comment: `\<flung\>` will match adjacent to a hyphen, and also next to a full stop, i.e. at end of sentence.

Answer (score 1):

```
"[A-Z]\\s?\\w*\\s?(([^(\\.\\s)|(\\?\\s)|(!\\s)])|\\s)*(?:your target\\s)(([^(\\.\\s)|(\\?\\s)|(!\\s)])|\\s)*(([^(\\.\\s)|(\\?\\s)|(!\\s)])|\\s)*[\\.|\\?|!]"
```

A sentence starts with any capital letter, in the middle it may contain decimal or abbreviation.

Comment: This one is in R

Comment: A direct solution is welcome, but please ensure you add context around it so your fellow users will understand how it solves the problem

Comment: Could you please explain this by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

```
(?<=^|\s)[A-Z][^!?.]*( word\s*)[^!?.]*(?=\.|\!|\?)
```

Before first capital letter there is a line start or a white space, then it may consist any characters without set of `[!?.](*)-`or may not , then contains your target word with or without white spaces after it (if it is in the end of the sentence), then may consist again any characters without set of `[!?.](*)-`or not, and finally ends with dot or `!` or `?`.