# Parse out single complete sentence containing a certain string pattern with regex

Tags: regex

I have a certain string of Chinese text:

> xxxxx。xxxx。xxx。xxx。xxxxx。xxxCxxxx。

How do I use regex to parse out the sentence containing the letter "C"?

> xxxCxxxx。

The regex:

```
/。.+?C.+?。/
```

gave this result:

```
"。xxxx。xxx。xxx。xxxxx。xxxCxxxx。"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Found the answer: `[^。]*C[^。]*`

Can anyone explain why `/[^。]*C[^。]*。/` works and `/。.+?C.+?。/` doesn't?

Comment: A similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26081820/6210219). I can delete this question if the community thinks this is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that: `[^。]*C[^。]*。`

To answer the problem with your original regex  `/。.+?C.+?。/` for which you wanted explanation as to why it didn't work would be :

1. it will first match `。`
2. Then `.+?C` will keep fetching characters until it finds C thus this
   entire thing would match : `xxxx。xxx。xxx。xxxxx。xxx`
3. Once C is being found, the last part of your regex `.+?。` would be in
   action. It fetches everything up to the next 。

   Therefore you get the result : `。xxxx。xxx。xxx。xxxxx。xxxCxxxx。`

This one `[^。]*C[^。]*。` works for you because:

1. `[^。]*C` fetches anything but 。 ; and those anything must be followed
   by C which makes it `xxxC`
2. `[^。]*。` it again fetches anything but 。 and stopped when it finds 。
   and matches it.