# Extract age from text in R

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr, text-extraction

I have a .csv-file with a column containing book descriptions scraped from the web which I import into R for further analysis. My goal is to extract the protagonists' ages from this column in R, so what I imagine is this:

1. Match strings like "age" and "-year-old" with a regex
2. Copy the sentences containing these strings into a new column (so that I can make sure that the sentence is not, for example "In the middle ages 50 people lived in xy"
3. Extract the numbers (and, if possible some number words) from this column into a new column.

The resulting table (or probably data.frame) would then hopefully look like this

```
|Description             |Sentence           |Age
|YY is a novel by Mr. X  |The 12-year-old boy| 12
|about a boy. The 12-year|is named Dave.     |
|-old boy is named Dave..|                   |
```

If you could me help out that would great since my R-skills are still very limited and I have not found a solution for this problem!

Comment: Maybe the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081820/regular-expression-to-extract-whole-sentences-with-matching-word could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
library(stringr)

description <- "YY is a novel by Mr. X about a boy. The 12-year-old boy is named Dave. Dave is happy."

sentence <- str_extract(description, pattern = "\\.[^\\.]*[0-9]+[^\\.]*.") %>% 
  str_replace("^\\. ", "")
> sentence
[1] "The 12-year-old boy is named Dave."

age <- str_extract(sentence, pattern = "[0-9]+")
> age
[1] "12"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have slightly edited the pattern to also include written numbers and to only include one- or two-digit numbers, but then your example works.

Answer (score 3):

Another option if the string contains other numbers/descriptions besides just age, but you only want age.

```
library(stringr)
description <- "YY is a novel by Mr. X about a boy. The boy is 5 feet tall. The 12-year-old boy is named Dave. Dave is happy. Dave lives at 42 Washington street."
sentence <- str_split(description, "\\.")[[1]][which(grepl("-year-old", unlist(str_split(description, "\\."))))]
> sentence 
[1] " The 12-year-old boy is named Dave"

age <- as.numeric(str_extract(description, "\\d+(?=-year-old)"))
> age
[1] 12
```

Here we use the string "-year-old" to tell us which sentence to pull and then we extract the age that is followed by that string.