# PCRE REGEX to match one or more sentences containing a set of characters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have blocks of text which contain only **one** specific HTML tag (i.e. the "mark" tag) and I want to extract a paragraph of all the contiguous "sentences" which contain that tag. A "sentence" in my use-case is delimited by a question mark, exclamation mark, full stop or semi-colon.

*EDIT: The "mark" tags are being generated automatically on the server-side and they are always well-formed. There is no risk of summoning cthulhu in my use-case.*

**What I have tried:**

Starting with the second result in [this PCRE regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26081843/572561), which works for selecting all sentences that contain the word "flung", see for example t[his regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/10). I have added semi-colons since those are in my use-case as well:

```
/[^.;?!]*(?<=[.;?\s!])flung(?=[\s.;?!])[^.;?!]*[.;?!]/igm
```

This works well, except for two issues that I still need help with:

- **How can I exclude decimal numbers e.g. 12.34 during the match?** E.g. "Lorem ipsum 12.34 dolor flung sit amet" should be one sentence. Currently, it takes the period in the decimal number as a punctuation, which it isn't. I suppose modifying the REGEX to detect if the decimal has a number or a letter around it will work, but I've attempted a look-ahead constraint such as `?:[^\.]|\.(?=\d)` but it doesn't match, or I'm not doing it right.
- **I would like to modify this to match **all** "mark" HTML tags instead of a word such as "flung"**. I know that REGEX isn't good for html tags, but an HTML parser can't recognize these characters either (? ! . ;). Maybe I could consider a combination of the two?

**What I expect:**

***Example 1: (basic match)***

`harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio? Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio <mark>cumque</mark> nihil impedit .23 quo minus id 0.89 quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, 12.34 omnis dolor repellendus! Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, quod maxime placeat`

should return

`Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio <mark>cumque</mark> nihil impedit .23 quo minus id 0.89 quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, 12.34 omnis dolor repellendus!`

since that is the sentence which contains the "mark" tag, and the decimal points are not full-stops.

***Example 2 (Any sentences that don't contain the tag *but are between* other tagged sentences will be included as well.)***

`At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do <mark>eiusmod</mark> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <mark>magna</mark> aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <mark>commodo</mark> consequat? Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur! Excepteur sint <mark>occaecat</mark> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum; sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam?`

should return the below (note how the sentence "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur!" was included even though it has no  tag, because it is between two other matched sentences).

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do <mark>eiusmod</mark> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <mark>magna</mark> aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <mark>commodo</mark> consequat? Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur! Excepteur sint <mark>occaecat</mark> cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this PCRE regex that meets your requirements:

```sh
((?<!\S)[^.?!;]*?<mark>.+?(?>[.?;!](?!\S)|\z))(?>(?>\h+.+?[.;?!])*?\h+(?1))*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/522)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert that we don't a whitespace before the current position
- `[^.?!;]*?`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not listed inside `[...]`
- `(?:\h+.+?[.?!;])*`: Match 0 or more sentences in between marked sentences
- `(?>[.?;!](?!\S)|\z)`: Assert that we don't a whitespace after the current position after matching sentence terminator or match end of input
- `(?1)` recurses the 1st subpattern

Comment: One last question, please. If the block of text has a final incomplete sentence (i.e. no termination) but contains at least one `mark` tag, is there a way to capture the rest of the available sentence regardless? E.g. `velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur! Excepteur sint <mark>occaecat</mark> cupidatat non proident, sunt in` should match from Excepteur to the end, even though it's an incomplete sentence. If it's not too complex to get there from your solution, can you please give me some pointers so I can play around with your answer? Thanks again.

Comment: I can probably tweak it but it won't be a small change since we are recursing whole subpattern. I have shutdown my computer for night as it is 3:42 AM here. I will attempt it tomorrow morning my time if you don't mind

Comment: Yes, that works for me. I really appreciate this! P.S. Meanwhile, the first sentence already matches even if it is incomplete. I only need this for the last sentence.

Comment: Can you try this: https://regex101.com/r/hP6gS1/521

Comment: Works great! Thanks a ton!!

Comment: I didn't know the concept of recursion in RegEx. After understanding this answer, I explored more about it at https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html.

Answer (score 1):

Other strategy: Since sentences between two sentences with `<mark>` in a same paragraph have to be included in the result, you can greedily match all that is between an opening tag and a closing tag that doesn't contain a newline (i.e. that is in a same paragraph).

```
~
(?<!\S)
(?> [^.?!;<]* (?:\.(?=\S))? )+
<mark> .* </mark>
.*? [.?;!]
(?!\S)
~ix
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nRop7/3)

Or the same optimized:

```
~
(?<!\S)
(?> [^.?!;<]* (?:\.(?=\S))? )+
(*SKIP)
<mark> (?> [^\n<]* < )+ /mark>
(?> [^.?;!]* [.?;!] )+?
(?!\S)
~ix
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nRop7/2)

Note: this problem can also be solved without regex, using [intlBreakIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/intlbreakiterator.createsentenceinstance.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I hope it comes in useful for someone else: I've accepted the other one and also upvoted this. Unfortunately for me, new lines / paragraphs are not clearly defined in the source of the text.

Comment: @Cogicero: for a trailing sentence without a punctuation mark at the end of a paragraph, you can change the pattern to that: https://regex101.com/r/4nRop7/4

Comment: @Cogicero: if paragraphs "are not clearly defined", how do you hope to find sentences enclosed between two sentences with `<mark>` in a same paragraph?

Comment: By "paragraphs are not clearly defined", what I mean is that there are no line breaks, no CRLF, in the text. It's just a block of text of unknown length, and sentences are defined using the punctuation symbols I mentioned. To find sentences between "marked" sentences, I expect to (1) "match" the sentences that are "mark"ed, and then (2) include anything between them as well, into the match. This means the match now contains part of a "paragraph" (a group of sentences, with some marked). The accepted answer does exactly this. Thanks again for submitting this! I hope it's useful to someone.